# what is use of $title_prefix and $title_suffix variable inside drupal theme system

Tags: theming

i am *intermediate* in php.i start learning drupal 7 theme system. i need to know what is role of  $title_prefix and $title_suffix variable inside .tpl.php files. what happen if we **not** include these variable inside .tpl.php files. i also read documentation for those variable at [drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/226776) but documentation is not enough to make it crystal clear.can anybody explain its use in simple words.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure how it could be any clearer than on the docs page, but here goes;

- `$title_prefix` is for content that should be displayed directly *before* the title in a template file (node.tpl.php, block.tpl.php, etc).
- `$title_suffix` is for content that should be displayed directly *after* the title in a template file.

There really is nothing more to it than that. If you choose not to include these variables in your template file then they simply won't be rendered.

Since any module/theme in the system has the chance to populate/change the values that are in either of these variables it's impossible to say exactly what will not be rendered in your particular case if you choose not to display them.

As an example, (and if I remember rightly), contextual links for blocks/nodes are contained in the `$title_prefix` variable. So if you don't print `$title_prefix` in your template, you won't get contextual links for that item.

Comment: Jut one thing: Contextual links are rendered in the `$title_suffix` variable, not in `$title_prefix`. Just checked twice in my theme.